# Angular - Create property in new property of object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, object, properties

Currently, I have a `select` element in my html which has a ngModel to the object `details`:

```
[ngModel]="details?.publicInformation?.firstname"
```

However, `publicInformation` may not exist in that object, or if it does, maybe `firstname` does not exist. No matter the case, in the end, I want to create the following:

```
[ngModel]="details?.publicInformation?.firstname" (ngModelChange)="details['publicInformation']['firstname'] = $event"
```

Basically, if the select is triggered, even if neither of  `publicInformation` nor `firstname` exist, I would like to create them inside `details` and store the value from the select.

The issue is that I am getting

```
Cannot set property 'firstname' of undefined
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here and how can I achieve the result I desire?

Comment: I understand why you've used `ngModelChange`, but `ngModel` provides you with two-way binding, so `[(ngModel)]` is sufficient and recommended. Initialize your object before it is evaluated in the template rendering process (principally what's suggested in the answers). By the way, it would be `$event.source.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `details` and `publicInformation` to empty object

```
public details = {publicInformation : {}};
```

Comment: I was hoping to achieve it without initializing it, but since it is not possible, this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that when you load the form data.

For example, you might have something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._someService.loadForm().then((formData: FormData) => {
        this.details = formData;
    });
}
```

Then, you could modify that to fill in the missing empty properties you need:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._someService.loadForm().then((formData: FormData) => {
        this.details = formData || {};

        if (!this.details.publicInformation) {
            this.details.publicInformation = { firstname: '' };
        } else if (!this.details.publicInformation.firstname) {
            this.details.publicInformation.firstname = '';
        }
    });
}
```

However, it would be better to place this logic in the services, so that they are responsible for adding all the necessary empty properties to the data they load, or if you are using Redux, then it should go into the reducers.